# Jacobian of $A (A^\top X A)^{-1} A^\top$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, jacobian

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $n\geq m$, be a full column rank matrix, and consider the function
\begin{align}
f&\colon \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\\
& X\mapsto A (A^\top X A)^{-1} A^\top,
\end{align}
where $\bullet^\top$ denotes transposition.

Assuming that $(A^\top X A)^{-1}$ exists, I'm interested in the computation of the Jacobian matrix of $f$, i.e.
$$\tag{1}\label{a}
\mathbf{J}[f] = \left[\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X_{ij}}\right]\in\mathbb{R}^{n^2\times n^2}.
$$

I know that there exists a closed form expressions for the Jacobian of the inverse, namely $\mathbf{J}[X^{-1}]=-(X^{-\top} \otimes X^{-1})$ (see e.g. [here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~pfackler/MatCalc.pdf), page 5). Hence, I wonder whether a similar closed-form expression can be derived for \eqref{a}.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$, matrix-valued function $\mathrm F : \mathbb R^{n \times n} \to \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is defined as follows

$$\mathrm F (\mathrm X) := \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top}$$

Hence,

$$\mathrm F (\mathrm X + h \mathrm V) = \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} (\mathrm X + h \mathrm V) \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} = \cdots = \mathrm F (\mathrm X) -  h \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm V \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top}$$

Thus, the *directional derivative* of $\mathrm F$ in the direction of $\mathrm V$ at $\mathrm X$ is the matrix-valued function

$$- \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm V \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top}$$

Making $\mathrm V = \mathrm e_i \mathrm e_j^{\top}$, we obtain

$$\partial_{x_{ij}} \mathrm F (\mathrm X) = - \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm e_i \mathrm e_j^{\top} \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} = \color{blue}{- \mathrm F (\mathrm X) \, \mathrm e_i \mathrm e_j^{\top} \mathrm F (\mathrm X)}$$

which is a multiple of the outer product of the $i$-th column and $j$-th row of $\mathrm F (\mathrm X)$.

Vectorizing the directional derivative, we obtain

$$\mbox{vec} \left( - \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm V \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} \right) = \color{blue}{- \left( \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X^{\top} \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} \otimes \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} \right)} \mbox{vec} (\mathrm V)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Before accepting it, I would like to ask you a (perhaps, silly) clarification. I’m a bit confused on the “right” notion of Jacobian for a matrix-valued function, namely between the classical one (your first blue formula) and the vectorized one (your second blue formula). For instance, if I would like to check whether or not the Jacobian is non-singular for a given positive definite $X$, which formula do I have to consider?

Comment: @Jacquard Take my formula and make $\mathrm A = \mathrm I_n$. You then obtain $- (\mathrm X^{-\top} \otimes  \mathrm X^{-1})$, which is the formula in the question and also in Fackler's notes. Hence, I suppose that is the "right" formula.

Comment: @Jacquard If $- \left( \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X^{\top} \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} \otimes \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} \right)$ is singular, then there is at least one direction $\mathrm V$ for which the directional derivative of $\mathrm F$ is zero. That would be one critical point.

Comment: @Jacquard The directional derivative is $- \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm V \mathrm A \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm A^{\top}$. If the *rows* or *columns* of $\mathrm V$ are in the left null space of $\mathrm A$, then the directional derivative is zero.

Answer (score 0):

For typing convenience, define the matrix
$$\eqalign{
\def\B{B^{-1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\qq{\qquad\qquad}
\def\vc{\operatorname{vec}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
B &= A^TXA \\
dB &= A^T\;dX\;A \\
d\B &= -\B\;dB\;\B \;=\; -\B A^T\;dX\;A\B \\
}$$
and use it to write the function and calculate its differential
$$\eqalign{
F &= A\B A^T \\
dF &= A\;d\B\,A^T \;=\; -F\;dX\;F \qq \\
}$$
from which one may obtain the componentwise *matrix-valued* gradients
$$\eqalign{
\grad F{X_{ij}} &= -F\,E_{ij}\,F \qq\qq\qq \\
}$$
or a vectorized *matrix-valued* gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad {\vc(F)}{\vc(X)} &= -{F^T\otimes F} \qq\qq\quad \\
}$$
or a *tensor-valued* gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad FX &= -F\,{\cal E}\,F^T \qq\qq\qq \\
}$$
where
${\cal E}$ is a fourth-order tensor whose components can be written in terms of Kronecker delta symbols as
$\,{\cal E}_{ijk\ell} = \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{j\ell}\;$
while
$\;E_{ij}$ is a matrix whose components are all zero except for
the $(i,j)$ component which is equal to one.