# what's the definition of the derivation of matrix function F(X)?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have problems with finding a definition for the derivation of a matrix function F(X) with
$F: \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p\times q} $
All I know is the derivation of vector functions.

Comment: Do you know the concept of total / frechet derivative?

Comment: $\Bbb R^{n\times m}$ is a vector space of dimension $nm$. $\Bbb R^{p\times q}$ is a vector space of dimension $pq$. $F$ is a vector function. Your derivation of vector functions is the derivative. Everything else is just a matter of how to interpret the result.

Comment: Take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2138449/339790